# Getting my data

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I manage a list of contact names, phone, fax, location/address, job title and department in a simple text file. That text file is then turned into a JSON file. I want to have drupal pages with departments of course, and under each department I want drupal to use that very JSON file to show only those in that department. How using very standard drupal methods can I do this. I am a new to drupal.

> The data is used for other purposes so I need it to stay outside drupal but when it is updated I want drupal to show those changes.

Comment: Although you linked to an answered question, the answer there gave a solution using a module that has long been in maintenance mode and worries me for the future. Not only that, the alternative suggested sent me down a many-hour rabbit hole. It is time for this question to be asked anew.